# Why does the glob `*[!t]*` return files whose names contain `t`s?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have really no idea after reading [glob (programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) of the results printed by following command in shell,  I'm using (bash) as my shell. Given this directory hierarchy:

```
/sub2
    s.py
    t2.txt
    nametoname.txt
    bees.txt
    /sub22
```

---

```
$ echo *[!t]*
bees.txt nametname.txt s.py sub22 t2.txt
```

In my understanding the arguments to `echo` will be expanded to match any filenames that *don't contain* the letter t, but the result was quite the opposite, why?

This command outputs all filenames that *contain* the letter t:

```
$ echo *[t]*
nametname.txt t2.txt
```

In the previous command I just negated `[t]` to `[!t]`, then in my expectation it should do the opposite of the second command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This glob:

```
echo *[!t]*
```

Will find any filename that at least one non-`t` character in it.

So, If you have filenames as `t`, `tt`, `ttt` then those filenames won't be listed using this glob.

**Solution:**

If you want to list filenames that don't have letter `t` in it then you can use this `find` command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name '*t*'
```

You may also add `-type f` for listing files only or `-type d` for listing directories only.

Comment: You should probably use `-name`, not `-iname` here, to be consistent with the glob's case strictness.

Comment: Then I can say `echo *[t]*` will match any filename that contains at least one t.

Answer (score 4):

`!` is the standard character for negating a bracket expression. `*[!t]*` means match zero or more arbitrary characters, followed by anything *except* a `t`, followed by zero or more arbitrary characters. In other words, match any file name that contains a character other that `t`. What it won't match are file names consisting *only* of `t`s: `t`, `tt`, `ttt`, etc.

If you only want to match filenames that don't contain *any* `t`, see Charles Duffy's answer, as he beat me to it.

Answer (score 4):

As other answers have given, `*[!t]*` returns files with *any* non-`t` character.

What they haven't yet provided is a workaround:

```
shopt -s extglob  ## enable extglobs
echo !(*t*)       ## list files with names not containing t
```

See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language